# Rails app with JRuby not working - Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jruby

I have a rails app which I am running on o sx 10.10.5 When I try to run the rails server I get this error:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found unexpected end of stream while scanning a quoted scalar at line 14 column 82
                             parse at org/jruby/ext/psych/PsychParser.java:227
                      parse_stream at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:376
                             parse at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:324
                              load at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.5.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/psych.rb:251
                             parse at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:60
        block in raw_configuration at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:56
                              call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:318
                           default at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:712
                                [] at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1100
                 raw_configuration at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:56
              global_configuration at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:64
                     configuration at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:32
                              each at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:42
                              load at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:36
                              load at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro.rb:23
                  block in Railtie at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5
                              call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:318
                      execute_hook at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36
           block in run_load_hooks at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45
                              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1560
                    run_load_hooks at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44
                   run_load_hooks! at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:148
                          instance at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:96
                            config at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:123
               <class:Application> at /Users/fariedpatel1/Documents/Maestrano/connector/config/application.rb:11
                <module:Connector> at /Users/fariedpatel1/Documents/Maestrano/connector/config/application.rb:10
                             <top> at /Users/fariedpatel1/Documents/Maestrano/connector/config/application.rb:9
                           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:937
                            (root) at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1
 require_application_and_environment! at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141
                           console at /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67
                             <top> at    /Users/fariedpatel1/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0@newconnector/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39
                        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:937
                             <top> at bin/rails:4
```

My gemfile:

```
ruby '2.2.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.0.5.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.6'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'puma'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'maestrano-connector-rails'
Object.send :remove_const, :Config
Config = RbConfig
group :production, :uat do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', platforms: :jruby
  gem 'pg', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test, :develpment do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', platforms: :jruby
  gem 'sqlite3', platforms: :ruby
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'timecop'
end
```

I am using `jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3) 2016-01-26 7bee00d Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.45-b02 on 1.8.0_45-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]`
and  Rails 4.2.7

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding my set up. I have had a number of issues setting this up. My previous error was showing that I need to change config to RB config, so as you can see I included this in my gemfile and that particular error has gone away.

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error in a yml file (perhaps a figaro related one)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I re-installed figaro, which has got rid of that error and left me with a new one - NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply have a syntax error in your figaro .yml configuration (check your config).

you could try parsing the file to verify its valid:

`require 'yaml'; YAML.load File.read('config/figaro.yml')`

... this is not a JRuby specific issue, you could confirm by boot-ing under MRI

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I re-installed figaro, which has got rid of that error and left me with a new one - NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

Comment: if your q is answered than accept an answer. answers are not a dedicated support forum for people asking questions until they're satisfied :) ... best!

Comment: This morning, I re-booted under MRI and everthing works perfectly. Sorry, I'm quite new to stack overflow.